# JSF Temporary Variable

Tags: jsf

Is there a way to temporarily save the value of calcuation in a JSF page?
I want to do the following without calculating twice:

```
<h:outputText value="#{complexModel.currencyAmount.currency}">
<h:outputText value="#{complexModel.currencyAmount.amount}">
```

I've tried using the alias bean but I get an error saying java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - row is unavailable.

e.g.

```
<t:aliasBean id="bean" alias="#{bean}" value="#{complexModel.currencyAmount}">
  <h:outputText value="#{bean.currency}">
  <h:outputText value="#{bean.amount}">
</t:aliasBean>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two ways (at least):

1. Using lazy-init field of your `complexModel`. something like:

   ```
   private Currency currencyAmount;
   public Currency getCurrencyAmount() {
       if (currencyAmount == null) {
           currencyAmount = calculateCurrencyAmount();
       }
       return currencyAmount;
   }
   ```
2. Using the JSTL `<c:set>` tag:

(the namespace first)

```
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
```

then

```
<c:set var="varName" value="#{complexModel.currencyAmount}" />
```

And then the calculated value will be accessible through `#{varName}`.

Comment: The first option - yes. The second - I have no idea.
One advice - when asking questions about obsolete version of a framework, mention this explicitly.

Comment: The first option doesnt really suit as I'm output the values in a datatable so the value is dependent on the row...I could have a map but its getting messy as this needs to be cleared when refreshing etc.

Answer (score -2):

In JSF 2.0,you can use `<ui:param/>` which it's powerful.

```
<ui:param name="foo" value="#{zhangsan.foo}"/>
```

Comment: Read section "<c:set> vs <ui:param>" here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense